# Discord .py Bot message.content

Tags: python, discord.py

Probably a pretty easy one but Im coding a discord bot

```py
if message.content.startswith('...'):
    await message.channel.send('...')
```

Currently, it works if someone's first word is ... (hence the `.startswith`) is there another attribute to scan the chat for keywords in the middle/end/beginning of the sentence?

Comment: does `if '...' in message.content:` solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look for occurrences of a substring in a string,

in the **beginning**, use:
`"string".startswith("substring")`

in the **middle**, use:
`"substring" in "string"`

in the **end**, use:
`"string".endswith("substring")`

**anywhere** in the string, use:
`"substring" in "string"`

---

These expressions will return `True` if was able to find the substring, and `False` if not.

So to answer your question directly, the following snippet should solve your problem

```py
if "substring" in message.content:
   # write code here
```